# Set specific var in Struct Array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I was wondering if there is an easy way to set a specific var in an array of struct elements?

**Example:**
What I have is:

```
var memberArray = [Member]()
struct Member {
var memberID : String!
var memberName : String!

   init(memberID : String! = nil,
        memberName : String! = nil) {

       self.memberID = memberID
       self.memberName = memberName
   }
}
```

So, how would I set e.g. the `memberName` of a specific Member by just knowing it's `memberID`?

Thanks for helping! :-)

Comment: Unrelated, but **never ever** declare properties as IUO which are initialized in an `init` method. If the properties are supposed to be optional declare them as regular optional (`?`), otherwise non-optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have to search for the index of the record you want, and then use that index to modify the specified field of that record:

```
if let index = arr.index(where: { $0.memberId == "123" })
{
    arr[index].memberName = "Fred"
}
```